# How to merge two rows in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I wanted to know if there is a function in R that will help me merge two rows. Right now my data is in the following shape

| Car_Type | Prod | Sale | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Civic | 120 | 67 | June |
| City | 192 | 112 | June |

If possible, I would like the data to take this shape:

| Car_Type | Prod | Sale | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Civic + City | 312 | 179 | June |

I have tried the aggregate function, which works, but it does not manipulate the entire data frame.

Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: ``df %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarise(Prod =  sum(Prod), Sale = sum(Sale), Car_Type = paste0(Car_Type, collapse=" + "))``

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` solution. It uses an auxiliary function `f` to separate the cases of numeric and character vectors and applies the necessary transformation.

```
library(dplyr)

f <- function(x){
  if(is.numeric(x))
    sum(x)
  else if(any(x[-1] != x[1]))
    paste(x, collapse = "+")
  else x[1]
}

df1 %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), f)) %>%
  relocate(Month, .after = last_col())
## A tibble: 1 x 4
#  Car_Type    Prod  Sale Month
#  <chr>      <int> <int> <chr>
#1 Civic+City   312   179 June
```